# ofstream- save a function to return a txt

Tags: c++, linux, ofstream

I'm trying to add dates in a txt file. But this is not coming out in a readable format for reading.

Someone could help me? I would be very grateful!, Thank you.

code

SAVE:

```
//...code....///

ofstream myfile ("text.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "date: " << date_function();
    myfile.close();
  }
```

DATE FUNCTION:

```
  void example::date_function(){
  //...code....///       
  clock = localtime(&attrib.st_atime);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", clock);
  cout << buf;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date function has a return type of `void` and you are inserting it into the file. That makes little sense perhaps you want something more like this:

```
void date_function(ofstream & ofs){     
  clock = localtime(&attrib.st_atime);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", clock);
  ofs << "date: " << buf;
  }

ofstream myfile ("text.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    date_function(myfile);
    myfile.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of date_function should be string.

```
  string example::date_function(){
      clock = localtime(&attrib.st_atime);
      strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", clock);
      return buf;
  }
```

(By the way, where have you defined `buf`? It's used in your question, but I don't see the definition?)